# using git on windows powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I'm trying to use git on powershell, but having trouble.
I was following Miguel Grinberg pycon workshop, and he clones with git clone " "
I know I can download git, and can be done with git bash. but I want to do the command on windows powershell. 
Can it be done outside of gitbash?

Comment: … have you just tried it outside of Git Bash after installing Git?

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded git from https://git-scm.com/download/win, then you could choose whether to modify PATH when you installed it:

[image: Git Setup]

If you chose "Use Git from Git Bash only", you will not be able to use it in the powershell, unless you add `X:\path-to-git-installation\cmd` to your PATH manually.

Otherwise, you should have no trouble using git in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If you download and install the git client for Windows, it will work in powershell.

https://git-scm.com/download/win

For example:

```
PS C:\Users\joeyoung> git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
PS C:\Users\joeyoung> git clone https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-pycon2015.git
Cloning into 'flask-pycon2015'...
remote: Counting objects: 70, done.
remote: Total 70 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 70
Unpacking objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
PS C:\Users\joeyoung> dir .\flask-pycon2015


    Directory: C:\Users\joeyoung\flask-pycon2015


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        31/08/2015     10:56            templates
-a---        31/08/2015     10:56        675 .gitignore
-a---        31/08/2015     10:56       3735 app.py
-a---        31/08/2015     10:56       3629 guess.py
-a---        31/08/2015     10:56       1083 LICENSE
-a---        31/08/2015     10:56         99 README.md
-a---        31/08/2015     10:56        112 requirements.txt


PS C:\Users\joeyoung>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I only need Git.exe, I extract Portable Git to a folder and add the following to my Powershell profile...

```
# Use the locally installed Git, if available.
$gitExecutable = Get-Command git.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Source
if ($gitExecutable -eq $null) {
    $gitExecutable = "$env:USERPROFILE\bin\PortableGit\bin\git.exe"
}

function Invoke-Git {
<#
.Synopsis
Wrapper function that deals with Powershell's peculiar error output when Git uses the error stream.

.Example
Invoke-Git ThrowError
$LASTEXITCODE

#>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [string[]]$Arguments
    )

    & {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
            [string[]]$InnerArgs
        )
        &$gitExecutable $InnerArgs
    } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable fail @Arguments

    if ($fail) {
        $fail.Exception
    }

}

Set-Alias -Name git -Value Invoke-Git
Set-Alias -Name git.exe -Value Invoke-Git
```